# 3DRotation for a Model3DGroup

Tags: wpf, 3d

I have a model3dgroup with a transform applied which looks like this,

```
<Transform3DGroup x:Key="B3OR34TR33">
                <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="0"
                                      OffsetY="-1.5748"
                                      OffsetZ="-8.10376e-011" />
                <ScaleTransform3D ScaleX="1"
                                  ScaleY="0.750021"
                                  ScaleZ="1" />
                <RotateTransform3D>
                    <RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                        <AxisAngleRotation3D Angle="90.0000025"
                                             Axis="1 0 0" />
                    </RotateTransform3D.Rotation>
                </RotateTransform3D>
                <TranslateTransform3D OffsetX="0"
                                      OffsetY="0.0259444"
                                      OffsetZ="5.51401" />
            </Transform3DGroup>
```

There is also an animation which animates the model3dgroup on loaded.

```
<DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                           BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                           Duration="0:0:0.9"
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="B3OR34"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Model3D.Transform).(Transform3DGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetX)">
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                      Value="-38.50234985" />
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9"
                                      Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                           BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                           Duration="0:0:0.9"
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="B3OR34"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Model3D.Transform).(Transform3DGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetY)">
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                      Value="0.02594435215" />
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9"
                                      Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                           BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                           Duration="0:0:0.9"
                                           Storyboard.TargetName="B3OR34"
                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Model3D.Transform).(Transform3DGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform3D.OffsetZ)">
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0"
                                      Value="5.514007568" />
                <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.9"
                                      Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

The model3dgroup is a cube with 5 geometries[top,bottom,front,back & side]. The problem is when i apply a behaviour to roatate the model3dgroup, the rotation happens about the mid of the x axis of one of the geometrymodel3d. What should i be looking at here to rotate about the center of the model3dgroup.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Center of the RotateTransform3D with the CenterX/Y/Z Properties

In your case the center have to be your applied translation

```
            <RotateTransform3D CenterX="0"
                               CenterY="-1.5748"
                               CenterZ="-8.10376e-011" />
```